# SQLite - Can we pass arguments to a .sql file from batch file?

Tags: sql, sqlite, batch-file

I would like to pass an argument from a batch file to SQL file(for SQLite). I had no luck finding this method online, is it possible to do? If not, is there any alternative way?

For example, here is what I wanted to do:

In batch file I wanted to pass `%arg1%` to `sqlTest.sql`:

```
@echo off
set arg1=%1
echo .quit | sqlite3.exe -init sqlTest.sql %arg1%"
```

In sqlTest.sql file:

```
.open "db/code_status.db"
SELECT FileName, FilePath, Author
FROM CodeStatus
LEFT JOIN CodeFile ON CodeStatus.ChangeId = CodeFile.ChangeId
WHERE WorkItemId = 2197
ORDER BY ModifiedDate ASC;
```

For  `WHERE WorkItemId = 2197`, I would like to replace `2197` to the argument value from batch.

Any solution?, thanks!

Comment: An alternate approach is to use a different script processor instead of sqlite3.exe.  Here's one (of mine) that will take arguments off the command line, reference environment variables, and import/include files containing configuration data: https://pypi.org/project/execsql/

Comment: @rd_nielsen Good suggestion, however, I cannot install/configure on the client side PC. That's why I use a simple batch and sql script.

Comment: How about storing pieces of your script as separate files, and using `copy` and `echo` to paste the pieces together, inserting your argument(s) in the appropriate place(s) to create the complete script prior to running it with sqlite3.  (*sed* or a Python or Awk script would be better for this, but presumably you can't install any of those.)

Answer (score 4):

You might try using the `param[eter]` dot-command of [sqlite command-line shell](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) (section15).

In this particular example, modify the sqlTest.sql:

- remove the `.open` line
- change `WHERE WorkItemId = 2197` to `WHERE WorkItemId = :id`

Then you *should* get the desired result with something like this batch script:

```
@echo off
sqlite3.exe "db/code_status.db" ".param set :id %1" ".read sqlTest.sql"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately  ".parameter set" command only works inside sqlite3(.exe) running. I don't think we can pass param data from Batch file like your idea. Because my command is simple enough... I just decided to put it all in the batch files instead of creating extra sql script. It's not smartest way but quick way to solve my problem :)

Comment: I understand that, which is precisely why the `.param` and `.load` are sent as _consecutive_ arguments to `sqlite3` in the batch file. I'm glad you got it to work. There is always more than one way to skin a cat :)

Comment: Thank you for this example on how to send parameters via command line. The official documentation lacks in examples in this department. I did have to change .load to .read in my instance however.